# What would you call a person who does a job but doesn't really care about the quality of his work?

Tags: word-request

Not really a 'slacker', since if I understand right, that's somebody who doesn't really do anything.
More like a person who works 9 to 5 (or more like 9-4 if he can get away with it) but not a minute longer. Is totally bland when fulfilling his tasks etc.
Also he's not really a 'tool' I guess, since he's 'using' his employer more the other way around.(?)

It's driving me crazy that I can't find a right word ;)

Comment: Riva, it is more natural to ask questions like this with the wording "What would you call". Saying "How would you call" is unnatural and not really used by native speakers.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. This is an artifact from my 1st language that still occasionally slips in ;)

Comment: @All - Thank you all for so many great tips! I didn't think I'll actually find so many new things to learn.  Also sorry for not choosing an answer yet. I didn't have a time to study all your posts yet and honestly they all seem good and right to me, so who to choose ? (I have up-voted most of answers, but I don't think I can flag more then one answer ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of difference idiomatic choices depending on what subtext you wish to convey. Here's a selection you can choose from:

If you want to describe someone with *implied criticism* in a single word:

> John is **[work-shy](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+work-shy)**.
>
> John is **[indolent](https://www.google.com/#q=define+indolent)**. (*not particularly common)*
>
> John is a **[do-nothing](https://www.google.com/#q=define+do-nothing)**. (*not particularly common).*
>
> John is very **apathetic** towards work.

Or using an idiom:

> John is somewhat of a **nine-to-fiver**.
>
> John does **enough to get by** at work.
>
> John does the **bare minimum** in his job.
>
> John isn't **living up to his own potential** at work.
>
> John is just **scraping by** at work.
>
> John is not **pulling his weight** in his job.

The following may also apply:

> John is very **unmotivated** in his work.
>
> John has **no passion** for his work.
>
> John is fairly **indifferent** towards his work.
>
> John is very **lazy**.

On the other hand, you might want to give John's lifestyle a positive spin:

> John has a **good work life-balance**.

Comment: Isn't it work-life balance? (notice the hyphen position)

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I think *slacker* is, in fact, the right word for this. You're describing someone who doesn't totally fail to show up, but puts in the minimum effort. Putting in the minimum effort is slacking.

If you wanted to describe this in a more "politically correct" way, you might say the person is **not very industrious**.

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know "slacker" does have that meaning.
I always heard and used it for a person who never wants to do or does _anything_.
So it actually isn't that harsh a word ?

Comment: I would say a 'slacker' is someone who shows up but puts in the minimum effort. A 'deadbeat' or a 'loser' is someone who doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 2):

***A goldbrick***: *a person who shirks responsibility or performs duties without proper effort or care.*

[Originally...](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-gol2.htm)

> The term has come a long way from its roots in the nineteenth century; along the way it got progressively further and further away from gold, or indeed bricks [...] Incompetent officers appointed from civilian life at the start of the
>   First World War with only minimal training were likewise called gold
>   bricks by enlisted men (in the case of second lieutenants, this was
>   probably provoked by their rank insignia, a gold rectangle)
>   At some point during that War, the term was extended to refer to
>   anybody not pulling his weight, a malingerer or loafer

Answer (score 2):

He's a [*clock-watcher*](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+clock+watcher&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). Only interested in when it's time to go home.

Answer (score 1):

Some other words that would work:

> John has a [casual, lackadaisical, negligent, disinterested, uncaring] approach to his work.

Some words that would also imply that the quality of work suffers from his approach would be slipshod, slapdash, unmeticulous, careless, and haphazard.

You can find more by consulting a thesaurus.

Answer (score 0):

I like

> "John's work is slapdash"

Since this describes his work, rather than John himself, it is more subtle than some of the other examples.

Answer (score 0):

What about

John is a **sloven** or **slob**.

This means **Schlamper** in German, which is a person who fulfills his job but the outcome is of such a poor quality.

Comment: A slob is someone who is untidy; and has a filthy appearance; a person very lazy in everything he does; and lacking in good manners. Slovenly, the adjective form is more common, has a similar meaning to slob, but you could describe someone's work as being slovenly.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a couple more:

John is a **malingerer.**

John is a **clockwatcher.**

From Google:

> **malingerer** : one who feigns illness in order to escape duty or work
>   **clockwatcher** : an employee who is overly strict or zealous about not working more than the required hours

Comment: Or worse yet, a **clockwatching malingerer**!

Comment: @snailboat: Why not?

Comment: I'm surprised this has garnered three unexplained downvotes. When I look up [malingerer](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+malinger&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) or [clockwatcher](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+clockwatcher&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t), those words seem to fit the O.P.'s question rather nicely. I suppose this answer might have been improved with a link or a supplied definition, but that's no reason for a downvote.

Comment: Unfortunately I see a pattern. "Malingerer" is a "funny" word (even if valid), as is "schlockmeister" and "skiver" in an answer below. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

A cobbler. And perhaps these might sound rude:

- schlockmeister
- skiver

Oh yes **slapdash** mentioned above is OK.

Comment: A [cobbler](https://www.google.com/#q=define:+cobbler) is someone who mends shoes, not someone who chooses not to work.

Answer (score -3):

A: **Confident.** There's something for everybody, and everything we put out into the world is for somebody. No matter how many haters of your work there are, there may be only a single fan out there who really loves your work. That one fan, whatever pleasure you inspired, is worth all the haters in the world.

Comment: This is. . . an interesting perspective, but the question isn't about art. It's about exactly reaching the line of requirement and nothing else, and *confident* doesn't really make sense in that context.